# For every unique value in column, create a new sheet + more

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in my macro that creates a new sheet for each unique value in a column (A) on worksheet "Main". It works fine right now.

```
Dim rLNColumn As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shDest As Worksheet
Dim rNext As Range


Const sLNHEADER As String = "CUSIP"


Set sh = Sheets("Main")
Set rLNColumn = sh.UsedRange.Find(sLNHEADER, , xlValues, xlWhole)


'Make sure you found something
If Not rLNColumn Is Nothing Then
    'Go through each cell in the column
    For Each rCell In Intersect(rLNColumn.EntireColumn, sh.UsedRange).Cells
        'skip the header and empty cells
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) And rCell.Address <> rLNColumn.Address Then
            'see if a sheet already exists
            On Error Resume Next
                Set shDest = sh.Parent.Sheets(rCell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0


            'if it doesn't exist, make it
            If shDest Is Nothing Then
                Set shDest = sh.Parent.Worksheets.Add
                shDest.Name = rCell.Value
                shDest.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "CUSIP"
                shDest.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Security"
                shDest.Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Broker"
                shDest.Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Shares"
                shDest.Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Debit"
                shDest.Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Credit"
                shDest.Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "Account"
                shDest.Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "Description"
                shDest.Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "Comments"
                shDest.Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "Process"
                shDest.Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "Origin"
                shDest.Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "Net Qty"
                shDest.Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Net Amt"
            End If


            'Find the next available row
            Set rNext = shDest.Cells(shDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            'Copy and paste
            Intersect(rCell.EntireRow, sh.UsedRange).Copy rNext


            'reset the destination sheet
            Set shDest = Nothing
        End If
    Next rCell
End If
```

Now, I realized that I don't need the unique values that only have 1 row associated with it in WS"Main". How can I reflect that in this code? Some sort of IF statement to say, if there is only 1 instance of this unique value in column A, do not create a new worksheet with it.

Also, for each worksheet created, each row is designated Debit or Credit. I can keep the Debit on the worksheet, but I need to take the Credit and move to another worksheet...

I can't write code to reference each new worksheet because it will not always be the same.

Clarification:

Let's say in column A ("CUSIP"), there are 3 unique values (A, B, C) each with 2 rows associated with it. 1 row will have a value in column E ("Debit") and 1 row will have a value in column F ("Credit"). After each unique value sheet is created with 2 rows each, I need to separate each worksheet by Debit and Credit (so basically take the credit row and move it to a new worksheet, for each unique value).

And the 2nd part - the values in column A are not the same for every report that I run this macro through, so I cannot reference specific worksheets by name or even by position..

Comment: I didn't notice your second question... Can you provide a little more information about the Debit vs. Credit issue? Which `another worksheet` do the credits need to be moved to? And what do you mean by `I can't write code to reference each new worksheet because it will not always be the same.`?

Comment: ARich, I added a bit of clarification via reply instead of commenting. Let me know if you understand what I'm saying. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please move your reply to the body of your question (since it isn't really an answer to your question). So let me make sure I understand: you need a debit sheet and a credit sheet for each unique value?

Comment: Yes - For all potential unique values in column A, I need to separate out by credit & debit. To make it easier, I have the Credit and Debit qualifiers in column N. Oh, also, the code you provided to ignore unique values with only 1 row associated works perfectly. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WorksheetFunction` `CountIf` for this ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx)).

I'd insert it into your code like this (**Untested**):

```
If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) And rCell.Address <> rLNColumn.Address Then
    'Check for multiple values.
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A:A"), rCell.Value) > 1 Then
        'see if a sheet already exists
        On Error Resume Next
            Set shDest = sh.Parent.Sheets(rCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        '. . .
```

Don't forget to close the additional `If` statement!